# Dual basis in a finite separable extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

I am reading the book *Algebras, Rings and Modules*, volume 1, by M. Hazewinkel and at the page 193 there is a proof about why the integral closure of a ring in a separable finite extension L over $k$ is finitely generated. I can't understand that point:

Let $ {W_1,...,W_n} $ a basis of $L$ over $k$. Then there is a dual basis $ {W_1^*,...,W_n^*}$ such that $ Sp(W_i,W_j^*)=δ_{ij}$  where $Sp$ is the trace. We can write $ W_J^*=X_1^jW_1+...+X_n^jW_n$ and for each $j = 1, ..., n$ this yields a system of linear equations: $$ \sum_{i=1}^n Sp(W_iW_k)X_i^J=Sp(W_kW_j^*)$$    $ (k=1,...,n)$ .
 Can anyone explain me how that system turns out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about what you do not understand. The map $\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}(x,y)\mapsto \tr(xy)$ is a non-degenerate bilinear form on the $K$-vector space $L$,because the extension $L/K$ is separable, hence the basis $(W_i)_{1\le i\le n}$ has a dual basis $(W_i^*)_{1\le i\le n}$. (As I haven't read the book, I have no idea why the trace form is denoted $\mathrm{Sp}$.)

The system of equations consists in writing the definition of a dual basis, so as to find the values of the coordinates  $X_i^j$ of each of the vectors $W_j^*$ in the basis  $(W_i)_{1\le i\le n}$ . So the system of equations really is:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \tr(W_iW_k)X_i^j= \delta_{jk}\qquad (1\le j,k\le n).$$

Comment: Thats exactly is my question( i was not clear before Bernard).Why that system is the definition of dual basis? In the proof we start from a basis $ w_1,..,w_n $  and we end to the dual $w_1^*,..,w_n^*$ through that system..

Comment: Not sure to get what you mean: is that clearer now?

Comment: It is clearer.We could prove that if the basis $ w_1^*,..,w_n^* $ is dual to $ w_1,..,w_n $ then $ tr(W_jW_k^*)=δ_{jk} $ , could we prove the opposite of this? if $ tr(W_jW_k^*)=δ_{jk} $ then $ w_1^*,..,w_n^* $ is dual?

Comment: We don't have to prove: it's the definition of a dual basis translated for this particular bilinear form.

Comment: Well, perhaps it is not clear to the OP *why* this bilinear form has a dual basis, i.e., why it is nondegenerate. That is exactly where the separability condition is needed (it certainly plays no direct role elsewhere).

Comment: The trace is denoted Sp because that is the start of the word Spur, which is German for "trace" (same non-technical meaning as in English, e.g., what an animal's tail might leave in the sand as it walks).

Comment: @KCd: Thanks for the information. It's more or less the same meaning for the French ‘trace’. I'll mention the separability condition in my answer.

Comment: @KCd, I’ll be the etymological pedant and say that Spur means track most exactly, and it’s not the tail that makes it but the footprints. The precise English cognate is “spoor”. I haven’t been to Germany, but in Denmark, the corresponding word is used in the train station for the track you find your train on.